# How do i deserialize this JSON containing arrays wrapped in json objects?

Tags: c#, json

I have tried so many answers on forums and many tutorials  to deserialize json arrays wrapped in json objects.. but for my case nothing help.

I am trying to deserialize this json from my wordpress demo site : https://mahdii.000webhostapp.com/?wpapi=get_posts&dev=1

I want to get posts name and author nickname.

What i have tried is :

```
string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://mahdii.000webhostapp.com/?wpapi=get_posts&dev=1");
Console.WriteLine(json);
var deserialize_post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

My Class:

```
public class Author
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string gravatar { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string title_plain { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public string excerpt { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public List<object> category { get; set; }
    public List<object> tag { get; set; }
    public List<Author> author { get; set; }
    public string comment_count { get; set; }
    public string comment_status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting null at deserialize_post I think I am doing it incorrectly Please I need help if someone can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)`

Comment: A quick glance says it should be `var deserialize_post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` and you can get your posts from `deserialize_post.posts`

Comment: Thanks haim770 and Equalsk but it doesn t work can u try to write the code it to get posts details as title,... and authors details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a dotnetfiddle example that fixes your serialization issues:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kpnYv0

Essentially, I took your data (which your site is getting the hug of death at the moment) and put it into the following logic:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://mahdii.000webhostapp.com/?wpapi=get_posts&dev=1");

    var deserializePost = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var postInfo = deserializePost
        .posts
        .Select(p => new 
                { 
                    Name = p.title_plain, 
                    AuthorNicknames = p
                        .author
                        .Select(a => a.nickname) 
                });

    Console.WriteLine(postInfo.Count());
}
```

I'm projecting only the specifically requested data into the `postInfo` variable.  You'll find that each post can have multiple authors, so the `AuthorNicknames` property of `postInfo` is also an IEnumerable.

For anyone else trying to help, here is the JSON returned by the site:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 2,
  "count_total": 2,
  "pages": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": "9",
      "type": "post",
      "slug": "e5t-hal-3al2a",
      "url": "https:\/\/mahdii.000webhostapp.com\/?p=9",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "e5t hal 3al2a",
      "title_plain": "e5t hal 3al2a",
      "date": "2017-02-09 19:35:05",
      "modified": "2017-02-09 19:35:05",
      "excerpt": "",
      "parent": "0",
      "category": [
        {
          "term_id": 1,
          "name": "Uncategorized",
          "slug": "uncategorized",
          "term_group": 0,
          "term_taxonomy_id": 1,
          "taxonomy": "category",
          "description": "",
          "parent": 0,
          "count": 1,
          "filter": "raw",
          "cat_ID": 1,
          "category_count": 1,
          "category_description": "",
          "cat_name": "Uncategorized",
          "category_nicename": "uncategorized",
          "category_parent": 0
        }
      ],
      "tag": [

      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "slug": "mahdi",
          "name": "mahdi",
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "nickname": "mahdi",
          "url": "",
          "description": "",
          "gravatar": "http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/b2f7652b7fd5e51e1ac71f6d23998c4c?s=100&d=mm&r=g"
        }
      ],
      "comment_count": "0",
      "comment_status": "open"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "page",
      "slug": "sample-page",
      "url": "https:\/\/mahdii.000webhostapp.com\/?page_id=2",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "Sample Page",
      "title_plain": "Sample Page",
      "date": "2017-02-09 12:31:52",
      "modified": "2017-02-09 12:31:52",
      "excerpt": "This is an example page. It's different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with &hellip; <a href=\"https:\/\/mahdii.000webhostapp.com\/?page_id=2\"> Continue reading <span class=\"meta-nav\">&rarr;<\/span><\/a>",
      "parent": "0",
      "category": [

      ],
      "tag": [

      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "slug": "mahdi",
          "name": "mahdi",
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "nickname": "mahdi",
          "url": "",
          "description": "",
          "gravatar": "http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/b2f7652b7fd5e51e1ac71f6d23998c4c?s=100&d=mm&r=g"
        }
      ],
      "comment_count": "0",
      "comment_status": "closed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: OP asked for the post name and author nickname, can you add an example of how to access those specific properties after deserialization?

Comment: @joe_coolish i am getting an error on Select word saying :

Author doesn t not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Author' can be found .

I Just want to get ALL posts details and all authors details ( how can i access them)

Comment: have you inspected `deserializePost`?  It should be all of the post data deserialized.  The `postInfo ` object was just the data that you had asked about in your question (the post name and author nickname).  If all the post data isn't available in the `deserializePost` object, let me know and I'll take a look specifically

Comment: .Select(a => a.nickname)  this Select is underlined with a red color not the first select above

Comment: @joe_coolish i just tested  var deserializePost = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

I am still getting NULL at deserializePost :s ( i used the breakpoints in xamarin)

Comment: Author should be a List (`public List<Author> author { get; set; }`), but it's acting like a single object.  The example I posted works on my machine.  If you want to get all of the data, just delete the 2 lines that involve `postInfo`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Cz9EE is a copy of the project I'm working with and it works just fine.  Check to make sure you're getting data and make sure the class structures are the same.

Comment: Woooow @joe_coolish the code works perfectly ! u are the coolest one who really solved the situtation when no one solved it.
Joe i really appreciate your help ! but one more question:

1-How could i store the post name and author nickname?
2- And how to attach them to a listview ?

Comment: @joe_coolish i am so sorry i can t vote this is my new account and i lost my previous one.
Wondering if i can share with you further questions on github or other.

Comment: I prefer SO, but you can accept the answer and that will be good enough for me :)  I'm rarely on GitHub, but my username over there is joecoolish.

Comment: @joe_coolish Sorry but u didn t tell me how to display the author nickname and post title in a textview .

Comment: TextView?  Is that a WinForm control?  I mainly work in ASP.NET.  If you have more code, feel free to ask another question and post it here.

Comment: @joe_coolish I am using xamarin to build an android,IOS project.
Just please how to save the retrieved post title and author nickname in a List or in a String, to do more work with them.

Comment: Have you looked up LINQ?  That is the best way to retrieve that information.  It's completely trivial to use and is worth learning

Comment: @joe_coolish yes i am learning now, iam new to LINQ.
But can u show me how to Console.WriteLine the post title after being retrieved ?